# how to pick phonebook contacts using phonegap with windows phone 8

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, windows-phone-8

in my html page i am havving one button for choose contact and one textbox which contains the value which contains phonebook contact number.i have tried below code,its working perfectly.but the problem is that file is xaml n i cant call this xaml file from my html page.so i want a code which is javascript with phonegap so that i can make a call from my html page and after picking contacts from my phonebook it shoulc come back to my same html page.this is the code i tried

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace CordovaWP8_2_8_02
{
    public partial class contact : UserControl
    {
        PhoneNumberChooserTask phoneNumberChooserTask;
        public contact()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            phoneNumberChooserTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
            phoneNumberChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
            phoneNumberChooserTask.Show();
        }
        void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The phone number for " + e.DisplayName + " is " + e.PhoneNumber);

                //Code to start a new call using the retrieved phone number.
                //PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
                //phoneCallTask.DisplayName = e.DisplayName;
                //phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = e.PhoneNumber;
                //phoneCallTask.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you even looked at the [Contacts Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/dev/doc/index.md)?

Comment: i gone through it but not getting how to use it in my code..i m new to this..if u know about this plugin in detail and how to use it in code..then pls tell me..